# "Он часто гулял с отцом" или "Они часто гуляли с отцом"?

Tags: синтаксис

Какое местоимение использовать, если речь идёт о двух людях? В моём примере это "он" и "отец".

1. Олег вспомнил своё детство. Он часто гулял с отцом. Он с отцом посещал выставки.
2. Олег вспомнил своё детство. Они часто гуляли с отцом. Они с отцом посещали выставки.

Второй вариант часто используется в разговорной речи (особенно конструкция вида "Мы с папой сегодня гуляли!"). Но правильно ли использовать подобный вариант с точки зрения правил русского языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения правил русского языка оба варианта эквивалентны друг другу.
Мне кажется дело в контексте:

- 1-ый вариант.         Если автор текста хочет лишний раз выразить многообразие увлечений и самодостаточный характер Олега. Так же если необходимо сфокусировать внимание на ГГ, то в любой части текста, автор постарается отбросить второстепенных и третьих лиц, лишь упоминая ГГ.
- 2-ой вариант.         Если автор текста хочет поближе раскрыть воспоминания из детства, акцентируя внимание, в данном случае, на отце Олега, как на запоминающемся Олегу человеке.